# Android button position fixed to bottom until scroll to its parent layout position

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to add a button to my layout which is fixed to bottom in the screen until user scroll and come to its proper location in the parent layout.

**Here the button stayed in the bottom while scrolling**

[image: Here the button stayed in the bottom while scrolling]

**when user scroll to come to its actual position in its parent layout then it viewed in its actual position, and remain here till scroll to end**

[image: when user scroll to come to its actual position in its parent layout then it viewed in its actual position, and remain here till scroll to end]

This feature should follow while the user scrolls up and exceed the button position.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want the button to stay always at the bottom? Please be more precise

Comment: post your xml..for better solution

Comment: I find my solution. Thanks to both of you for your interest.